Cython: Pythran as numpy backend on Windows 11
I'm trying to use Pythran as numpy backend in Cython as described here:
Cython Documentation
But unfortunately I run into an issue.
This is my testfile, testfile_cython.pyx:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# distutils: language = c++
# cython: np_pythran=True

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp


cpdef test_cython(cnp.int32_t num):
    cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=1] arr = np.arange(0,num, dtype=np.float64)
    arr = arr + 1
    
    return arr

That I build with the setup.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy
import pythran

setup(
    name = "testfile_cython",
    ext_modules = cythonize('testfile_cython.pyx'),
    include_dirs = [numpy.get_include(), pythran.get_include()]
)

Using the cmd command: setup.py build_ext --inplace gives then the following output:
Compiling testfile_cython.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing testfile_cython.pyx
c:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:381: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: c:\Pythran_Test\testfile_cython.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
running build_ext
building 'testfile_cython' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DENABLE_PYTHON_MODULE -D__PYTHRAN__=3 -DPYTHRAN_BLAS_OPENBLAS -Ic:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages/pythran -Ic:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_core\include -Ic:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\pythran_openblas\include\openblas -Ic:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_core\include -Ic:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages/pythran -Ic:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\include -IC:\Users\Sebi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\Sebi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tptestfile_cython.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\testfile_cython.obj -O2 /std:c++14 /w
cl : Befehlszeile warning D9025 : "/W3" wird durch "/w" überschrieben
testfile_cython.cpp
c:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages\numpy\_core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
c:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages/pythran\pythonic/include/types/ndarray.hpp(482): error C2559: "std::enable_if<`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::is_numexpr_arg<F>::value&&std::is_same<bool,F::dtype>::value&&F::value==1&&!`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::is_pod_array<F>::value,`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::numpy_vexpr<`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::ndarray<T,pS>,`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::ndarray<long,`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::pshape<long>>>>::type `anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::ndarray<T,pS>::operator [](const F &) const": kann eine Memberfunktion ohne ref-Qualifizierer nicht mit einer Memberfunktion mit ref-Qualifizierer überladen
c:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages/pythran\pythonic/include/types/ndarray.hpp(703): note: Siehe Verweis auf die gerade kompilierte Klasse Vorlage-Instanziierung "`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::ndarray<T,pS>".
c:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages/pythran\pythonic/include/types/ndarray.hpp(498): error C2559: "std::enable_if<`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::is_numexpr_arg<F>::value&&std::is_same<bool,F::dtype>::value&&F::value!=1&&!`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::is_pod_array<F>::value,`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::numpy_vexpr<`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::ndarray<T,`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::pshape<long>>,`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::ndarray<long,`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::pshape<long>>>>::type `anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::ndarray<T,pS>::operator [](const F &) const": kann eine Memberfunktion ohne ref-Qualifizierer nicht mit einer Memberfunktion mit ref-Qualifizierer überladen
c:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages/pythran\pythonic/include/types/ndarray.hpp(506): error C2559: "std::enable_if<`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::is_numexpr_arg<F>::value&&!`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::is_array_index<F>::value&&!std::is_same<bool,F::dtype>::value&&!`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::is_pod_array<F>::value,`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::numpy_vexpr<`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::ndarray<T,pS>,F>>::type `anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::ndarray<T,pS>::operator [](const F &) const": kann eine Memberfunktion ohne ref-Qualifizierer nicht mit einer Memberfunktion mit ref-Qualifizierer überladen
c:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages/pythran\pythonic/types/numpy_expr.hpp(200): error C2244: "`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::numpy_expr<O,Args...>::fast": Keine Übereinstimmung für Funktionsdefinition mit vorhandener Deklaration gefunden
c:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages/pythran\pythonic/types/numpy_expr.hpp(198): note: Siehe Deklaration von "`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::numpy_expr<O,Args...>::fast"
c:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages/pythran\pythonic/types/numpy_expr.hpp(200): note: Definition
...
...
...
c:\Pythran_Test\.Pythran_virtualenv\Lib\site-packages/pythran\pythonic/include/types/ndarray.hpp(506): error C2559: "std::enable_if<`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::is_numexpr_arg<F>::value&&!`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::is_array_index<F>::value&&!std::is_same<bool,F::dtype>::value&&!`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::is_pod_array<F>::value,`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::numpy_vexpr<`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::ndarray<__pyx_t_5numpy_float64_t,`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::pshape<long>>,F>>::type `anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::ndarray<__pyx_t_5numpy_float64_t,`anonymous-namespace'::pythonic::types::pshape<long>>::operator [](const F &) const": kann eine Memberfunktion ohne ref-Qualifizierer nicht mit einer Memberfunktion mit ref-Qualifizierer überladen
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

So building the .pyd file failed.
Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong? I would be happy if someone here could help me!

Additional information:
Trying to compile the testfile_cython.pyx without
# cython: np_pythran=True

works.
Trying to compile a file using pythran only also works. E.g. this file testfile_pythran.py:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np

#pythran export test_pythran(int)
def test_pythran(num):
    arr = np.arange(0, num)
    return arr

Successfully compiles with the cmd command pythran testfile_pythran.py -e -O3 -ffast-math -mfpmath=sse -funroll-loops -fopenmp -march=native -std=c++11 -fno-math-errno -w -fvisibility=hidden -fno-wrapv -DUSE_XSIMD -DNDEBUG 
I have the following python modules installed:
beniget==0.4.2.post1
Cython==3.0.11
gast==0.6.0
numpy==2.1.3
ply==3.11
pythran==0.17.0
pythran-openblas==0.3.6

This is the content of the pythran-win32.cfg (original):
[compiler]
defines=
undefs=
include_dirs=
libs=
library_dirs=
cflags=/std:c++14 /w
ldflags=
blas=pythran-openblas
CC=clang-cl.exe
CXX=clang-cl.exe
ignoreflags=

I'm using Windows 11 with the following Buildtools installed:


I'm not sure it currently works. The Pythran tests look to be disabled on Cython because at some point Pythran changed their interface and it no longer compiled correctly. Possibly I'm missing something, but it looks like it's been untested for a while
